# Некорректно отображается Дата и Время мз MySQL в React

Tags: mysql, reactjs, база-данных, дата, время

В базе данных создал таблицу со строкой date с типом DATETIME и с VALUE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. В БД все прекрасно отображается - 2022-10-25 16:10:08, а в React при запросе туда вот так отображается - 2022-10-25T12:10:08.000Z. Как получить такое значение даты и времени как и в БД? За одно подскажите пожалуйста, как отобразить формат даты как: 'dd-mm-yy, hh:mm'?

Comment: Это React так интерпретирует значения. Самое простое решение - в запросе преобразовать тип в строковый (DATE_FORMAT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
const inputDate = '2022-10-25T12:10:08.000Z';
const date = new Date (inputDate);

const year = date.getFullYear();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1; //В js месяц с 0 идет, потому +1
const day = date.getDate();
const hours = date.getHours();
const minutes = date.getMinutes();

console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}`);
```

Учтите, что в моем варианте дата считается по UTC и бужеь выводится согласно тайм зоне юзера. Если что это можно тоже настроить как надо.

Вариантов много и в инете инфы полноооо, даже на этом же стаке. Найти изи.